# Download a large file via curl

Tags: bash, curl

I'm working on a docker container on a remote server and need to download a large zip file of the NYU v2 dataset.

I know how to download small files using curl like the following:

```
curl -L -o newName.zip https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1fdFu5NGXe4rTLYKD5wOqk9dl-eJOefXo
```

But because the file is large, the download is broken

Would appreciate some help

Comment: curl has no problem downloading huge files, i guess you're just not properly quoting your urls.. but it's its an unstable internet connection that's the problem, try `--retry 99` , now curl will retry 99 times before giving up if the connection is unstable '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `bash` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$(mkdir -p "Data/")
echo "Downloading Data"
fileid="1fdFu5NGXe4rTLYKD5wOqk9dl-eJOefXo"
filename="nyu_data.zip"
curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileid}" > /dev/null
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=${fileid}" -o "Data/"${filename}
$(rm cookie)
```

This will put the zip file in a created Data directory